# How do I use Entity framwork on an existing database with out migrations?

Tags: entity-framework

I have an existing database that has tables like Surface, that hold different surfaces (not plural like `EF` seems to like).

I have created a type that uses `data annotations` thus:

```
[Table("Surface")]
public class Surface
{
    [Key]
    public Guid SurfaceKey { get; set; }
    public string SurfaceType { get; set; }
}
```

And I've create an `entity framework` context, and `repository` etc. Now when I access this in an MVC view, I get a message that the

> 'The model backing the 'EFDbContext' context has changed since the database was created...'

What difference does it make if it's changed? I might not have typed in something or another.

So what? I'm not asking `EF` to use my database. I have an existing database, I need to map it to classes, `Entity Framework` should quietly oblige, with no stupidity of `migration`. I'm not `migrating`. Every time I do a rebuild, it should start from scratch.

I just want to access my existing database, and if I compile with a typo, it should be forgotten when I correct the error and recompile.

How do I do this?

Comment: Is this still a question? If not, delete or close it.

Answer (score 0):

You configure this feature in the context class that you create.

```
public class MyContext : DbContext
{
    static MyContext()
    {
        Database.SetInitializer<MyContext>(null);
    }

    //....
}
```

[Here](http://www.west-wind.com/weblog/posts/2013/Mar/26/Firing-an-Entity-Framework-Database-Initializer-from-within-DbContext)'s a useful link regarding database initialisers